# How do `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage `, `UIImagePickerControllerCropRect `, and `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage` relate?

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I was hoping someone could explain how these values are related. (I'll put my interpretation in a self-answer, and see how well it holds up).

I'm working on a feature where a user picks an image, and then is offered a square crop boundary, which they can use if they want.

So, I'm using `UIImagePickerController` with `allowsEditing`

The docs aren't especially enlightening ->

> Specifies the cropping rectangle that was applied to the original image
>   https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller/infokey/1619150-croprect

I was doing edge case testing, so I cropped a pano that someone sent me. Here's the relevant results when I dump data via `print`:

`"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage": <UIImage: 0x6000014aed80> size {4032, 3024} orientation 1 scale 1.000000,`

`"UIImagePickerControllerCropRect": NSRect: {{0, 0}, {3071.9999999999995, 2307.710144927536}},`

`"UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage": <UIImage: 0x6000014a2290> size {826, 620} orientation 0 scale 1.000000,`

Comment: related: most of my other tests show the edited image as 640x640, so, this result had gotten my attention, as being "too big".

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation is:

Take the `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` (4032, 3024), and then crop it with `UIImagePickerControllerCropRect`, from the origin, razor off anything outside of ~3072 x 2308.

Then the final image was returned as (826, 620), I'm guessing that the cropped mage was scaled to the values. (The aspect ratios of all three look very consistent)